# Get Google App Engine LocationId at runtime

Tags: python-3.x, google-app-engine, google-cloud-platform

The new Cloud Tasks python libraries require location as task creation parameter. I can always look up the location and hardcode it, but everything else, including the project name, is available through environment variables. Is there a way to get the locationId (eg. `us-central1`) from python3 standard environment?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The REST API (and presumably the [python client library](https://github.com/googleapis/google-api-python-client)) for AppEngine can return the location id if you know the application name:

https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/admin-api/reference/rest/v1/apps/get

The Application object that is returned has a "locationId" key.

However, note that the [cloud tasks documentation](https://cloud.google.com/tasks/docs/dual-overview) calls out 2 exceptions to verbatim using this identifier: `europe-west` and `us-central` need to be passed to tasks as `europe-west1` and `us-central1` respectively.

Comment: Well spotted. The new libraries and apis are a bit of a design mess...

Answer (score 0):

It's possible to get this information from the [Metadata server](https://cloud.google.com/appengine/docs/standard/python3/runtime#metadata_server). Accessing http://metadata.google.internal/computeMetadata/v1/instance/region from your app will return a string of the form 'projects/[numeric-project-id]/regions/[locationId]'.